# Crear botón expandible Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito crear un botón que pueda expandirse y mostrar información determinada, algo como el de uber cuando te muestra la información del conductor que te asignaron, que muestre una imagen y que al expandirlo pueda mostrar una imagen mas grande o algo por el estilo

Comment: Tienes una captura de pantalla? para entender mejor el fecto

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar un *ExpandableLayout*, tal vez esta Librería  te sirva.

https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout

Salu2.

Comment: lo que busco es que se expanda con un gesto o click, como cuando expandes una notificacion